# Javascript: nested loops?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to achieve an animation/sequence like this:

the animation starts with a loop (imagine a **car** moving from x1 to x2) then a pause of 1 second then again the animation (imagine a **car** moving from x2 to x3 etc)

the **car** loop is achieved adding 1px to the car left: value

but i cant figure out the nested loop how should work

i'm trying to do ti only using setInterval, no jquery

**UPDATE: sorry i wasnt clear**

but assume we have

```
var animation = setInterval(car_moves, 10);
```

how do i trigger this animation every 2 seconds, and the animation should last 0.5sec ?

Comment: `the car loop if for instance achieved adding 1px to the car left: value`can you explain what this means ???

Comment: If you want a hint take a look at using a while loop. That would allow you to run the animation until the car has gone a specified distance.

Comment: yes, but i'd rather see how it works in pure javascirpt with no delay()

Comment: easy enough, when you mean x1 to x2, do you mean from 1 to 2 horizontally?

Comment: I've updated my answer to do this without jQuery.

Comment: `how do i trigger this animation every 2 seconds, and the animation should last 0.5sec ?` you start interval for every 2 seconds, in which you initialize your animation interval for 10 milliseconds and, simultaneously, start setTimeout for 0.5 second for the function that will run and clear your animation interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, this is done with jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/qCx69/

```
$('img').animate({left: '100px'}, 2000, function() {
    $(this).delay(1000).animate({left: '300px'}, 2000);
});
```

interacting with

```
<img src='http://boydstire.com/img/car_img.jpg' id='car'
     style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:100px;'>
```

or without it (this one is not an optimized solution)
http://jsfiddle.net/8bZTA/1/

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    update_car(100,1);
}, 50);

function update_car(x,path)
{
  var car = document.getElementById('car'), 
      pos = parseInt(car.style.left) + 1;
  car.style.left = pos + 'px';
  if (pos > x)  
  {
      clearInterval(timer);
      if (path!=2)
      {
      setTimeout(function(){ //pause
       timer = setInterval(function(){update_car(200,2);}, 50);}
           , 5000);
      }
  }
}
```

**Updated:**

You can even make a set of stops and motions (it can be update for variable speed too)
http://jsfiddle.net/hFH4U/5/

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){update_car();}, 50);

var path = {'path1': 100, 'pause1': 2000, 'path2': 200, 
               'pause2': 2000, 'path3': 220}, 
                cur_step = 0, steps = [], speed = 1;
for (var i in path)  steps.push(i);

function update_car()
{
  var car = document.getElementById('car'), 
      pos = parseInt(car.style.left);
  if (/^path/.test(steps[cur_step]))
  {
      // motion part
      if (pos > path[steps[cur_step]])
          cur_step++;
  }
  if (/^pause/.test(steps[cur_step]))
  {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        cur_step++;
        timer = setInterval(function(){ update_car(); }, 50);
      }, path[steps[cur_step]]);
  }
  if (cur_step >= steps.length) // end animation
      clearInterval(timer);

   car.style.left = (pos + speed) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: "yes, but i'd rather see how it works in pure javascirpt with no delay()" read comments...

Comment: @Francesco Ok, I wrote you another example

Comment: this sound close to what i meant... i'll give it a try

Comment: @Francesco check another example with different steps in the path.

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/BVEmF/1/

An object oriented approach:

```
// example showing linear movement
function car() {
   this.car = document.getElementById("car");
   this.style = this.car.style;
   this.delay = 2000; // 2 secs
   this.position = 0;
}

car.prototype.moveBy = function(m) {
   var me = this;
   setTimeout(function() {
      me.animate(m);
   },this.delay)
}

car.prototype.animate = function(m) {
   var me = this, i=0, 
   r = setInterval(function() {
      ++i;
      me._move(i);
      if(i === m) {
         me.position += i;
         // stop animation
         clearInterval(r);
         // delay again
         me.moveBy(m);
      }
   },77);
}

car.prototype._move = function(i) {
   this.style.marginLeft = i+this.position+"px";
}

Car = new car;
Car.moveBy(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a traditional loop, you should take a look at setTimeout and setInterval.  The first argument to those calls is a function where you would draw the car or move the car.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested loop. You can use something like setInterval to accomplish this. Keep in mind I'm using jQuery to get the target element by id.

```
var interval = setInterval(IncreasePosition, 1000); // 1000 is in milliseconds
function IncreasePosition() {
    var targetElement = $("#targetElementId");
    // TODO: Get current padding value
    // TODO: Increment to it
}
```

That method (IncreasePosition) will get called every second and increase the padding.

Comment: yes but with this you have a sudden transition, where I want to keep 10ms between every pixel

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Here's the straight up javascript/html/Css...all you need is a suitable car.jpg file...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hi</title>
<style>
#car {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var last_x = 0;
var some_arbitrary_stopping_point = 200;
var x = self.setInterval("move()", 100);

function move() 
{
    last_x += 5;
    document.getElementById('car').style.left = last_x + 'px';
    check_pos_car();
    return last_x;
}

function check_pos_car()
{
    if (last_x > some_arbitrary_stopping_point)
    {
        x = window.clearInterval(x);
    }
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="car.jpg" id="car" alt="A beetle">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code has been tested by the way and accomplishes what you were asking for. You could do just as well without the whole stylesheet and with the if in `check_pos_car()` in `move()` of course