# javascript animation: do I need nested setInterval?

Tags: javascript

I'm reformulating my question you can found here:
[Javascript: nested loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107758/javascript-nested-loops)
because I believe I wasn't clear and the solutions didn't nail my problem.
let me try to make ti more clear:

Assuming I have an animation `animation(n)` that is a function that randomly delete the first letter of every word in a a web page (i know is weird but is just an example for the question's sake), and I want the user to see letters disappearing with a random timing (a sequence of animations, variable speed and pauses)

assuming

```
function animation(n){

// n is the numer of letters to remove
// code to remove the letter

}
```

how do i trigger this animation() every 2 seconds, and the animation should last 0.5sec ?

or random approach:

how do i trigger this animation() every n (n>0 && n<2) seconds, and the animation should last n (n>0 && n<2) seconds ?

I've been trying using setInterval but I'm kinda lot now

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a random number generator like so:

```
function animation(){
    //your code here
    setNewAnimation(); //set another call at random
}

function setNewAnimation() {
    setTimeout(animation, Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1)*1000); //random between 1-3 seconds
}

window.onload = function() {
    setNewAnimation() //initial call
};
```